# How to convert nested array to hash or JSON with values as array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, hash

I have this nested array

```
array = [["Colorado", "Adams County"], ["Colorado", "Jefferson County"], ["California", "Amador"], ["California", "Tulare"]]
```

I am expecting this

```
{"Colorado" => ["Adams County", "Jefferson County"], "California" => ["Amador", "Tulare"]}
```

I tried these:

```
array.to_h
#=> {"Colorado"=>"Jefferson County", "California"=>"Tulare"}

b = Hash.new
array.uniq.map{|k,v| b[k] = v}
#=> {"Colorado"=>"Jefferson County", "California"=>"Tulare"}

array.uniq.map{|k,v| b[k] << v}
#=> Error

array.map{|k,v| b[k] = [v]}
#=> {"Colorado"=>["Jefferson CountyAdams CountyJefferson CountyAdams County"], "California"=>["TulareAmadorTulareAmador"]}`
```

How can I get the values as an array?

Comment: What is the difference between `array` and `c`? (What is `array` in the first place?) What is `b`?

Comment: sorry i was working something on console, i have edited variables now. it should be more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first call `group_by` and then `transform_values` (Ruby 2.4+):

```
hash = array.group_by(&:first)
# => {"Colorado"=>[["Colorado", "Adams County"], ["Colorado", "Jefferson County"]], "California"=>[["California", "Amador"], ["California", "Tulare"]]}
hash.transform_values! { |value_list| value_list.map(&:last) }
# => {"Colorado"=>["Adams County", "Jefferson County"], "California"=>["Amador", "Tulare"]}
```

If your ruby doesn't have `transform_values`, you can just `map!`:

```
hash = array.group_by(&:first)
hash.each_value do |value_list|
  value_list.map!(&:last)
end
# => {"Colorado"=>["Adams County", "Jefferson County"], "California"=>["Amador", "Tulare"]}
```

Comment: How about `each_value`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to regroup the array of arrays by the first element.

```
array
  .group_by { |k, _| k }
  .each_value { |a| a.map! { |_, v| v } } # => {"Colorado"=>["Adams County", "Jefferson County"], "California"=>["Amador", "Tulare"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[["Colorado", "Adams County"], ["Colorado", "Jefferson County"],
 ["California", "Amador"], ["California", "Tulare"]].
   each_with_object(Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }) do |(k, v), h|
     h[k] << v
   end
#⇒ {
#  "California" => [
#    [0] "Amador",
#    [1] "Tulare"
#  ],
#    "Colorado" => [
#    [0] "Adams County",
#    [1] "Jefferson County"
#  ]
# }
```

Or, for Ruby 2.4+:

```
[["Colorado", "Adams County"], ["Colorado", "Jefferson County"], 
 ["California", "Amador"], ["California", "Tulare"]].
   group_by(&:shift).transform_values(&:flatten)
```

Comment: Oh, I like the shift one. But how about `array.group_by(&:shift).each_value(&:flatten!)`? Works in earlier Ruby versions as well and is a bit shorter.

Comment: cool.. `.each_value` is also great. Just wondering, is it possible to sort array value with `.sort` along with `flatten` ?

Comment: Speaking of sorting... is the output shown above really what you got from that code? Did it really make "California" come *before* "Colorado"? Doesn't that violate the "key insertion order"?

Comment: @StefanPochmann it’s how `pry` outputs the result: it sorts hashes.